# setting up passenger: keeps showing apache default page instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, centos, passenger

I am trying to get passenger to work but i keep seeing the apache default page instead. I am using centos 6.3 on an inmotion VPS. Here is what I've done so far:

1. gem install passenger.
2. rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module
3. pasted the following code into /usr/local/apache/conf/includes/post_virtualhost_global.conf (this gets loaded into httpd.conf)

   `LoadModule passenger_module /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   PassengerRoot /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17
   PassengerRuby /home/username/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ruby`

   `<VirtualHost 123.123.123.123:80>
       ServerName http://XXXXXX.inmotionhosting.com
       # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
       DocumentRoot /home/username/rails/current/public
       <Directory /home/username/rails/current/public>
          # This relaxes Apache security settings.
          AllowOverride all
          # MultiViews must be turned off.
          Options -MultiViews
       </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>`

   edit: not sure why this isnt formatting properly. its lined and tabbed fine in the text editor.
4. in etc/hosts there is the line:

   `123.123.123.123 XXXXXX.inmotionhosting.com XXXXXX`
5. i restarted apache via sudo service httpd restart in /etc/init.d
6. still shows apache default page

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Check the apache server access logs to see the incoming requests. Check the catalina logs (or other) to see any lingering error.

Comment: probably you need to enable site, try running: sudo a2ensite <yoursite> and then: sudo service httpd reload

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this 1 year old post for the similar problem but none of the comment worked for me. So I'm just adding my 2 cents for those who are looking for some help.

If you are seeing Apache default page, it means that phusion passenger is probably not running. You might have seen a warning message when you started/stopped/restarted the apache server that says the phusion passenger module is already loaded, skipping.

So Apache has skipped the most recent LoadModule line you added in the conf file.

Then check the error.log which is in the directory set for error log in apache config file. (httpd.conf for centos)

In my case, it was complaining that it couldn't find the watchdog in the directory set in PassengerRuby. This confirms that the passenger module loaded is NOT what I just added. This might have happened because I am using RVM now but also installed an old version of Passenger a while ago as a root. So I looked at the config.d directory under Apache root, there was a file "passenger.conf" that was loading the old version of Passenger.

I deleted the file, kept the new LoadModule as is - copied from the instruction Phusion Passenger gave me while installing apache2-module, restarted the apache server, no warning message, and passenger worked.